# Convert Date to year month representation

Tags: r, date, posixct, lubridate

I have a `Date`, and am interested in representing it as an integer of `yyyymm` form.  Currently, I do:

```
get_year_month <- function(d) { return(as.integer(format(d, "%Y%m")))}
mydate = seq.Date(from = as.Date("2012-01-01"), to = as.Date("5012-01-01"), by = 1) 
system.time(ym <- get_year_month(mydate))
#    user  system elapsed 
#    5.972   0.974   6.951
```

This is very slow for large datasets.  Is there a faster way?  Please provide timings for your answers so they can be easily compared. Use the above example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using functions from the `lubridate` package can be almost twice as fast as your function :

```
mydate = as.Date(rep("2012-01-01",1000))
library(lubridate)
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(get_year_month(mydate),
               year(mydate)*100+month(mydate))
```

gives :

```
R> Unit: milliseconds
                               expr      min       lq   median       uq
             get_year_month(mydate) 2.150296 2.188370 2.218176 2.285973
 year(mydate) * 100 + month(mydate) 1.220016 1.228129 1.239704 1.284568
```

Comment: great! looks like `lubridate` `month` and `year` functions are much faster than `base`. using `base` functions increases the time substantially.

Answer (score 3):

You can try using `yearmon` class from `zoo` package. In general if you are doing timeseries manipulation and analysis, I would suggest using `xts` or atleast `zoo` class. `xts` has lot of functionality for analysis of very huge timeseries data.

Here is quick benchmark against other suggested solutions.

```
get_year_month <- function(d) {
    return(as.integer(format(d, "%Y%m")))
}
mydate = as.Date(rep("2012-01-01", 1e+06))

microbenchmark(get_year_month(mydate), year(mydate) * 100 + month(mydate), as.yearmon(mydate, format = "%Y-%m-%d"), times = 1)
## Unit: milliseconds
##                                     expr       min        lq    median        uq       max neval
##                   get_year_month(mydate) 1049.8813 1049.8813 1049.8813 1049.8813 1049.8813     1
##       year(mydate) * 100 + month(mydate)  434.1765  434.1765  434.1765  434.1765  434.1765     1
##  as.yearmon(mydate, format = "%Y-%m-%d")  249.6704  249.6704  249.6704  249.6704  249.6704     1
```

Answer (score 2):

It would be best to keep your Dates in `POSIXlt` format if you want to manipulate them like that:

```
> system.time(ym <- get_year_month(mydate))
   user  system elapsed 
  4.039   0.025   4.079 
> system.time(mydatep <- as.POSIXlt(mydate))
   user  system elapsed 
  3.576   0.016   3.603 
> system.time(ym <- (1900 + mydatep$year)*100 + (mydatep$mon + 1))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.010   0.005   0.015
```

It's still a little faster, and you get subsequent similar operations for free, in terms of time.

Comment: a bit unfamiliar with `POSIXlt` but it doesn't look like it provides the same answer...

Comment: Whoops, my bad. Corrected my answer. `$year` gives the number of years after 1900, and `$mon` the number of months after January. For details `?POSIXlt`.

Answer (score 0):

There may not be a faster way for a single item. However you can make a version of the function that operates on collections run much faster than linearly by using builtin replicate   e.g.

```
function mydate(D) {
  x <- replicate(dim(D)[0], get_year_month(..)
  return(x)
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. i'm not sure what it means unfortunately. could you please provide an example as the other two.

Comment: Hi Alex, Please look up the use of the builtin "replicate", which will avoid the penalty of looping N times (N being the number of entries in your array) .

Comment: `replicate` is just `lapply`.. still no idea what you mean. post an example as the others have with timings. this might clear up some confusion.